# `QTextEdit` cursor becomes frozen after overriding its `dropEvent`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

In a program, I want to accept drag and drop of a file into a `QTextExit` in order to edit certain parts of it.

The drag and drop works fine, however after a file is dropped in the `QTextEdit`, the `QTextEdit`'s cursor becomes frozen (stops blinking and can no longer be moved).

Here is a minimal example:

After drag-and-drop: 
(d&d works fine, but cursor freezes)

[image]

I can edit the content in the textEdit, but the cursor remains visible after the textEdit loses focus.
[image]

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5 import Qt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    from Drag_drop_window import Ui_Form # import QtDesigner file

class override_textEdit(Qt.QTextEdit):  # override drop event for QTextEdit
    drop_accepted_signal = Qt.pyqtSignal(str) # the signal sends the file name to other widget
    def __init__(self):
        super(override_textEdit,self).__init__()
        self.setText("123")
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if len(event.mimeData().urls())==1: # accept event when only one file was dropped
            event.accept()
            self.drop_accepted_signal.emit(event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile())

        else:
            Qt.QMessageBox.critical(self,"Accept Single File Only","Accept Single File Only",Qt.QMessageBox.Abort)

            event.ignore()

class myWidget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myWidget, self).__init__()
        self.main = Ui_Form()
        self.main.setupUi(self)

        self.main.textEdit = override_textEdit()
        self.main.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.main.textEdit)
        self.main.textEdit.drop_accepted_signal.connect(self.slot)

        self.show()

    def slot(self,filename):
        self.main.lineEdit.setText(filename) # display file name in lineEdit



if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_Qt_Program = myWidget()

    my_Qt_Program.show()
    sys.exit(Application.exec_())
```

Drag_drop_window.py generated by QtDesigner

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Drag_drop_window.ui'
#
# Created: Sun Apr  5 17:53:03 2015
#      by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.3.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found that adding the following four lines to the end of the `dropEvent` makes things work:

```
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setText("")
        dummyEvent = QtGui.QDropEvent(event.posF(), event.possibleActions(),
                mimeData, event.mouseButtons(), event.keyboardModifiers())

        super(override_textEdit, self).dropEvent(dummyEvent)
```

You've overridden the `dropEvent` method of the `QTextEdit` control, but you're not calling the overridden superclass method.  I guess that there is some cleanup code in the overridden method that needs to run in order to sort out the issues you were having with the cursor.  However, simply calling the superclass method with the drop event, i.e.

```
        super(override_textEdit, self).dropEvent(event)
```

doesn't do what you are hoping for.  This enters the URL of the dropped file into the text-edit control.

I didn't find that any combination of calling `accept()`, `ignore()` or `setDropAction(Qt.IgnoreAction)` before calling the superclass `dropEvent` had any effect.  I suspect that the superclass method makes its own decisions on whether to accept or ignore the event, which may override what your subclass will have done.

So instead I create a 'fake' drag-and-drop event, identical to the one received except that the text data is empty, and pass this fake event onto the superclass.  Of course, the superclass is welcome to insert this empty text somewhere if it wants to, but if it does it's not going to have any effect.